# Getting up to date with the new features of c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have just discovered that i need to start looking for a new job.  I have been working in basic features of c# 3.0 and i was never give the chances to play around with c# 4.0.
What is the best way to get up to date with all the new features in the framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is the way that works for you. Are you the sort of person who learns how to do a task:

- by trying to do the task
- by reading about the task
- by being tutored one-on-one by an expert in the task
- by listening to lectures about the task
- something else

?

We don't know how you learn, so we cannot answer the question. How do you learn best? It makes no sense at all to recommend a book to read if you're the sort of person who hates learning things from books but loves learning things by doing them.

Answer (score 4):

all or any of following would help.

- Read blogs
- Read books
- watch videos on msdn
- Read SO discussions

Answer (score 2):

Read the blogs, books, tutorials, watch videos, try sample applications and work at home. Once you've mastered the new features of .NET 4.0 you will have arguments to convince managers to give you the chance to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN latest news feed IMHO is a very good starting point to discover new features, the RSS is here:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=84795&clcid=409

Above this I check a lot of blogs, such as:

http://encosia.com/

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the past couple of relases of C#, the new features this time are scattered all over. Pick some area that you think will really map into your career, like the parallel computing enhancements, or dynamic language support. If you've been doing a lot with generics, pick up the covariance and contravariance; they'll help a lot in some situations. I understand Expression support is improved as well; if you're a LINQ addict, you can probably do fun stuff with Expressions and expanding LINQ or writing your own query provider. If you work with COM, then look into the optional and named parameters.  Many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gmail account, set up the associated Reader and add C# blog feeds. That is my wat of keeping up to date. Of course it would not to hurt to read the blogs as well.